# Is there any ways to set "noReset" Appium capability only for one test?

Tags: selenium, appium

I wanna compare the data between closing app and launching it again. If I don't set noReset capability to true all the data clear up, but I need this option only for couple of tests, no more.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
   try {
        driver.terminateApp("appPackage");
        driver.activateApp("appPackage");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```